# Why doesn't it make sense to preprocess data with PCA before classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, pca

For some classification algorithms, assuming independence of data helps reduce the number of parameters to estimate. Why then not just to apply a method like PCA (or ICA) to the original features to get a set of independent features, apply these easy classification algorithms and project back the results on the original feature space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods like PCA do not create independent features. They create orthogonal features.

Independence implies orthogonality, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Yes; independence of two features (X,Y) means the joint distribution f(X,Y) can be factorized into a product of its marginals f(X)f(Y) while orthogonal means E(XY)=0; x and x^2 are orthogonal but dependent